# Show the Volterra Operator is compact using only the definition of compact

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

The Volterra operator $V:L^{2}[0,1]\rightarrow L^{2}[0,1]$ is defined by $(Vf)(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$.

I am wondering if it can be shown that $V$ is compact by definition - that is, either that $V$ maps bounded sets to precompact sets, or equivalently, that for any bounded sequence $(f_n)$ in the domain, $\{Vf_n\}$ has a convergent subsequence.

I have seen an elegant proof of the compactness of $V$ using the Arzela-Ascoli theorem.  Also, I have come across proofs using the notion of Hilbert-Schmidt operators.  However, both of these notions were foreign to me when I was assigned this problem, and I am curious if I can show $V$ is compact without using these ideas; unfortunately, I am not sure how to proceed directly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To directly show that $V$ maps bounded sets to precompact sets, the only idea I have would be to replicate most of the proof of Ascoli's theorem.

We can show it semi-directly, though, by exposing $V$ as the norm-limit of operators with finite-dimensional range.

For $1 \leqslant k < n$, let

$$\lambda_{n,k}(f) = \int_0^{k/n} f(t)\,dt,$$

and

$$\chi_{n,k}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 &, \frac{k}{n} \leqslant x < \frac{k+1}{n}\\ 0 &, \text{ otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Define

$$V_n(f) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \lambda_{n,k}(f)\cdot \chi_{n,k}$$

for $n \geqslant 1$. Then $V_n$ is a continuous operator with finite-dimensional range. For $0 \leqslant k < n$ and $\frac{k}{n} \leqslant x < \frac{k+1}{n}$, we have

$$\lvert V(f)(x) - V_n(f)(x)\rvert = \left\lvert\int_{k/n}^{x} f(t)\,dt \right\rvert
\leqslant \sqrt{x-\frac{k}{n}}\cdot \lVert f\rVert_{L^2} \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\lVert f\rVert_{L^2},$$

and hence $\lVert V - V_n\rVert \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. Thus $V$ is the norm-limit of operators with finite-dimensional rank, therefore compact.

Comment: Is the basis for the range of $V_n$ given by $\{ \chi_{n,1}, \chi_{n,2}, ..., \chi_{n,n-1} \}$? Perhaps this is obvious, and in fact appears to me to be quite easy to see, but one can never be too sure.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that is the basis. It is sufficient that these span the range to conclude that the range is finite-dimensional, we don't need the linear independence, but since that is easy to see here, there's nothing to be gained from not stating it.

Comment: Why $\int _a^b f(t)dt\leq \sqrt{b-a}||f||_{L^2}$? Don’t we have $||f||_{L^2}=\sqrt{ \int _0^1 f^2(t)dt}$?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof that
$$Tf(t) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt,\qquad L^p(0,1)$$
is compact for all $1<p<\infty$.
Here I adapting Kolmogorov-Riesz' theorem (see [Theorem 5 here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0906.4883.pdf)) on $L_p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to functions on the torus $\mathbb{T}$ and prove the following result:

> ***Theorem:*** Suppose $\mathcal{G}\subset L_p(\mathbb{T})$ is bounded, and that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is $\delta>0$ such that
> $$\int_{\mathbb{T}}|f(x)-f(x+h)|^p\,dx<\varepsilon^p,\qquad f\in\mathcal{G}$$
> for all $|h|<\delta$. Then, $\mathcal{G}$ is relatively compact (a.k.a. totally bounded) in $L_p(\mathbb{T})$.

A proof of this result is presented at the end.

***Solution to OP:*** Extend all $f$ as periodic functions with period $1$ (i.e. funtions in $\mathbb{T}$. Similarly, extend $Tf(x)$ as periodic functions with period $1$, $Tf(0)=0$. Suppose $\mathcal{F}\subset L_p(\mathbb{T})$ is $L_p$ bounded, say by $M>0$. By Jensen's inequality, for all $f\in \mathcal{F}$
$$\|Tf\|^p_p=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\big|\int_{\mathbb{T}}\mathbb{1}_{[0,x]}(t)f(t)\,dt\big|^p\,dx\leq\int_{\mathbb{T}}\int_{\mathbb{T}}\mathbb{1}_{[0,x]}(t)|f(t)|^p\,dt\,dx\leq\|f\|^p_p\leq M^p$$

On the other hand, by Holder's inequality (here $1<p<\infty$ plays a role)
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{T}}|Tf(x+h)-Tf(x)|^p\,dx&=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\Big|\int_{\mathbb{T}}\mathbb{1}_{[x,t+h]}(t)\,f(t)\,dt|^p\,dx\\
&\leq\int_{\mathbb{T}}\|f\|^p_p |h|^{p/(p-1)}\,dx=M^p\|h|^{p/(p-1)}<\varepsilon^p
\end{align}$$
for all $|h|<(\frac{\varepsilon}{M})^{p-1}=\delta$.

This shows that $\mathcal{G}:=\{Tf:f\in\mathcal{F}\}$ is bounded in $L_p(\mathbb{T})$, and $\mathcal{G}$ is equicontinuous in $L_p(\mathbb{T})$.  Theorem are satisfied and so, $\mathcal{G}$ is relatively compact in $L_p(\mathbb{T})$.

---

***Proof of Theorem:***
Divide $\mathbb{T}$ in $n$ arcs of length $\frac{1}{n}$, $n\geq\frac{2}{\delta}$. Define $P$ to be the projection of $L_p(\mathbb{T})$ onto the space generated by the indicator functions $\mathbb{1}_{\big(\tfrac{j-1}{n},\tfrac{j}{n}\big]}$, that is
$$Pf(x)=n\sum^n_{j=1}\Big(\int^{j/n}_{(j-1)/n} f\Big)\mathbb{1}_{\big(\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}\big]}(x)$$
Clearly $P$ is a bounded operator on $L_p(\mathbb{T})$, and $\|Pf\|_p\leq \|f\|_p$. Furthermore, as $P(L_p(\mathbb{T}))$ is finite dimensional, $P$ is compact and so, $P(\mathcal{G})$ is relatively compact in $L_p(\mathbb{T})$.

By Jensen's inequality, for any $f\in \mathcal{G}$
$$\begin{align}
\|f-Pf\|^p_p&\leq\sum^n_{j=1}\int^{j/n}_{(j-1)/n}|f(x)-Pf(x)|^p\,dx\\
&=\sum^n_{j=1}\int^{j/n}_{(j-1)/n}\Big|n\int^{j/n}_{(j-1)/n}(f(x)-f(u))\,du\Big|^p\,dx\\
&\leq\sum^n_{j=1}n\int^{j/n}_{(j-1)/n}\int^{j/n}_{(j-1)/n}|f(x)-f(u)|^p\,du\,dx\\
&\leq\sum^n_{j=1}n\int^{j/n}_{(j-1)/n}\int^{1/n}_{-1/n}|f(x)-f(x+h)|^p\,dh\,dx\\
&\leq n\int^{1/n}_{-1/n}\int_{\mathbb{T}}|f(x)-f(x+h)|^p\,dx\,dh<2\varepsilon^p
\end{align}
$$
From this, it follows that $\mathcal{G}$ is also relatively compact.