# About the Volterra operator and the approximation property

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

I need some help with these questions.

$\bullet\;$ First of all, if we define the Volterra operator $V:L^{1}[0,2\pi]\rightarrow L^{1}[0,2\pi]$ as $(Vf)(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$, Is this operator compact?
(I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707706/show-the-volterra-operator-is-compact-using-only-the-definition-of-compact) question , where it is proved in the case the operator is defined over $L^{2}[0,1]$, but I don't think the proof can be adapted to this case).

$\bullet\;$ And the other doubt I have is whether or not the space $L^1[0,2\pi]$ has the approximation property. This would give us that the Volterra operator defined as above (if it is compact) would be limit of finite rank operators.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $V$ is compact. The image of unit ball under $V$ is a bounded subset of $L^1$ that is also bounded in the $BV$ norm (total variation). Such a set is precompact in $L^1$: see [$L^1$ Compactness of Bounded BV Sets](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0212198) by Isidore Fleischer.

Upon request, I supply a self-contained argument. Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in the unit ball of $L^1$. Denote $F_n= Vf_n$. Observe that $F_n(0)=0$ and the total variation of $F_n$ is at most $1$. Use the representation of BV functions as a difference of two increasing functions: $F_n=\phi_n-\psi_n$ where $\phi_n(0)=\psi_n(0)=0$ and $\phi_n(1)\le 1$, $\psi_n(1)\le 1$.

Enumerate rational numbers in $[0,1]$ as $(q_k)$. Choose a subsequence of $\phi_n$ that converges at $q_1$; from it, choose a subsequence that converges at $q_2$, ... then take diagonal subsequence $(\phi_{n_d})$, which converges at all rational numbers. Let $\phi$ be the limit function, so far defined only at rational numbers. Extend it to $[0,1]\setminus \mathbb Q$ by $$\phi(x) = \sup \{\phi(q) :  q<x, q\in \mathbb Q$$
The result is an increasing function on $[0,1]$, also denoted $\phi$. Being increasing, it is continuous except on a countable set. At each  point  of continuity of $\phi$, we have 
$$\phi(x) = \lim \phi_{n_d}$$
(this is not hard to check). By the dominated convergence theorem, $\phi_{n_d}\to \phi$ in $L^1$.

Starting with $\phi_{n_d}$, repeat the argument for $\psi_{n_d}$, extracting a further subsequence that converges in $L^1$. Along this subsequence, $F_n$ converge in $L^1$. $\Box$

---

Yes, $L^1$ has an approximation property, because it has a Schauder basis: the [Haar system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet#Haar_system_on_the_unit_interval_and_related_systems) is one such basis. Separable Banach spaces without an approximation property are  artificial constructs; they do not occur in the wild.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, user147264. But, for the first question, do you know some direct proof, using the definition, similar to the one given in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/707706/show-the-volterra-operator-is-compact-using-only-the-definition-of-compact ?

Comment: Ok, i'll read it carefully to see if I get it.

Comment: Everything clear now, words. Thanks a lot!!